# Error while starting datanode daemons of hadoop

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop

I am trying to set up fully distributed hadoop cluster with three laptops. The details are:

Operating system --> Ubuntu 16.01 LTS, x64 bit OS.
Hadoop version --> hadoop-2.7.3

laptop #1 --> 192.168.1.2 --> Acting as Master (Running ResourceManager and Namenode daemons)

laptop #2 --> 192.168.1.3 --> Acting as slave (Running Datanode and NodeManager daemons)

laptop #3 --> 192.168.1.6 --> Acting as slave (Running Datanode and NodeManager daemons)

When I start the Datanode daemon (in either of slaves) , I am getting the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: All directories in dfs.datanode.data.dir are invalid: "/hadoop/tmp/dfs/data/"
```

Can anyone help me understand what is the meaning of this error and how to correct this?

Is this error because of some permission issues or do i need  to run the datanode daemon as sudo, like : `sudo hdfs datanode`

Comment: Does data nodes have this directory created (with correct permissions)?

Comment: What permissions do i need to have?  I gave permission of 777 . Also, since the user with which I am logged into the system (userA, for example) isn't a root, so do I need to use ` sudo hdfs datanode` ?

Comment: No, if you are using `sudo` you're doing something wrong and you may need to `chown` or `chmod` some directories.

Comment: @Jedi: So does this mean we have to change the ownership of the directory based on the id we have to run the hadoop daemons?

Comment: First try make sure all directories have 777 permissions recursively `chmod -R /hadoop/tmp/dfs/data/`, then restart data nodes.

Comment: Noooo. No cargo culting. No `777`. Just set the correct owners.